# Django template: src attribute doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've been doing some practice with Django and lately I ran into a problem that I can't solve.

I'll give you some context.

I have this models (I think you can just focus on the fact that the model has a gitUrl function):

```
class AllTemplates(models.Model):
    categories = [
        ('landing-page', 'landing-page')
    ]
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=categories, default='landing-page')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def templateNumber(self):
        try:
            number = self.id
        except:
            number = ''
        return number

    @property
    def templateTitle(self):
        try:
            title = self.name
        except:
            title = ''
        return title

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

    @property
    def gitUrl(self):
        try:
            gitPath = self.url
        except:
            gitPath = ''
        return gitPath
```

The purpose of this model is to keep all the templates I develop in the database. Each template has various fields including 'url', in which I store the github url where the template in question is located.

**What I can't do is**: dynamically make each template have an html file, in which there is an iframe tag whose src attribute points to the github url.

**Here's what I tried to do.**

My urls.py (the row that interests the case is the one containing the dynamic url, the last one):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'websiteEcomm'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('landing-page/', views.landingPage, name='landing-page'),
    path('preview/<str:siteTitle>/', views.preview, name='preview'),
]
```

My views.py(the function that interests the case is the one called 'preview', i.e. the last one):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
allTemplates = AllTemplates.objects.all()
landingPage = AllTemplates.objects.filter(category='landing-page')

context = {'allTemplates': allTemplates, 'landingPage': landingPage}


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'websiteEcomm/home.html', context)


def landingPage(request):
    return render(request, 'websiteEcomm/landingPage.html', context)


def preview(request, siteTitle):
    siteTitle = AllTemplates.objects.get(name=siteTitle)
    website = AllTemplates.objects.all()

    previewContext = {'siteTitle': siteTitle, 'website': website}
    return render(request, 'websiteEcomm/preview-templates/base.html', previewContext)
```

At this point I created an html file called 'base.html' in which to insert the 'iframe' tag. The content of 'base.html' is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> {{siteTitle}} - Free Attitude Template</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <iframe src="{{website.gitUrl}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything works except the src attribute of the 'iframe' tag, which is empty. This is the structure of 'base.html' when viewed in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Medicio - Free Attitude Template</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your view is sending `website = AllTemplates.objects.all()` , which is a queryset,.  But in your template you have `src="{{website.gitUrl}}"`, so which gitUrl do you want displayed there?  You could display *all* of them by iterating.  Or, maybe what you want is `src="{{siteTitle.gitUrl}}"`?

Comment: Yes, what I wanted was src="{{siteTitle.gitUrl}}". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to correct `src="{{siteTitle.gitUrl}}"` instead of `src="{{website.gitUrl}}"` like this...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> {{siteTitle}} - Free Attitude Template</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <iframe src="{{siteTitle.gitUrl}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```